# Locking a file in Python

Tags: python, file-locking

I need to lock a file for writing in Python. It will be accessed from multiple Python processes at once. I have found some solutions online, but most fail for my purposes as they are often only Unix based or Windows based.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up going with the code I wrote <strike>[here, on my website](http://www.evanfosmark.com/2009/01/cross-platform-file-locking-support-in-python/)</strike> <sup>[link is dead, view on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20140531203736/http://www.evanfosmark.com:80/2009/01/cross-platform-file-locking-support-in-python/)</sup> ([also available on GitHub](https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock)). I can use it in the following fashion:

```
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("myfile.txt.lock"):
    # work with the file as it is now locked
    print("Lock acquired.")
```

Comment: I implemented something similar, and just found that it broke in some configurations since NFSv2 does not support atomic exclusive file creation.

Comment: As noted by a comment at the blog post, this solution isn't "perfect", in that it's possible for the program to terminate in such a way that the lock is left in place and you have to manually delete the lock before the file becomes accessible again.  However, that aside, this is still a good solution.

Comment: is it the same as http://pythonhosted.org/lockfile/lockfile.html ? it seems to be compatible, but I am not sure... If it's the same, the `from filelock import FileLock` doesn't work, use `from lockfile import FileLock` instead...

Comment: @cedbeu It looks like the link you submitted might have a different author (Skip Montanaro) than the author of this answer (Evan Fosmark). I don't know if it could still be the same code passed off to a different maintainer.

Comment: Yet another improved version of Evan's FileLock can be found here: https://github.com/ilastik/lazyflow/blob/master/lazyflow/utility/fileLock.py

Comment: Using 2 threads and heavy load (just continuous iteration: saving consecutive numbers to file), both the original FileLock and @superbatfish improved version cause, after some time, under Windows: fd = os.open( self.lockfile, os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_RDWR ): OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'counter_test.txt.lock'. Minimal test: http://cdn.anonfiles.com/1403402648742.py

Comment: I dislike this solution because filelock leaves stale lock files behind which are not cleaned up at the next attempt.

Comment: OpenStack did publish their own (well, Skip Montanaro's) implementation - **[pylockfile](https://github.com/openstack/pylockfile)** - Very similar to the ones mentioned in previous comments, but still worth taking a look.

Comment: @jweyrich Openstacks pylockfile is now deprecated. It is advised to use [fasteners](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasteners) or [oslo.concurrency](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/oslo.concurrency) instead.

Comment: Another similar implementation I guess: https://github.com/benediktschmitt/py-filelock

Comment: This implementation is incorrect, or at least it is outdated now. From the documentation: `Don't use a FileLock to lock the file you want to write to, instead create a separate .lock file` Source: https://pypi.org/project/filelock/

Comment: @harbun The `fasteners` library has no documentation whatsoever and therefore this is a bad recommendation.

Comment: This clutters the file system with millions of lock files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The comments make it very confusing whether this is still the recommended package to use or whether we should be using something newer. An update to the answer would be really nice.

Comment: How can we install it via `pip3 install filelock` ?

Comment: @Evan Fosmark is it possible to use FileLock as a reader writer lock ?
i want to be able to read a file from multiple processes in parallel but only one process can write to the file at any given time

Answer (score 55):

The other solutions cite a lot of external code bases. If you would prefer to do it yourself, here is some code for a cross-platform solution that uses the respective file locking tools on Linux / DOS systems.

```
try:
    # Posix based file locking (Linux, Ubuntu, MacOS, etc.)
    #   Only allows locking on writable files, might cause
    #   strange results for reading.
    import fcntl, os
    def lock_file(f):
        if f.writable(): fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
    def unlock_file(f):
        if f.writable(): fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    # Windows file locking
    import msvcrt, os
    def file_size(f):
        return os.path.getsize( os.path.realpath(f.name) )
    def lock_file(f):
        msvcrt.locking(f.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_RLCK, file_size(f))
    def unlock_file(f):
        msvcrt.locking(f.fileno(), msvcrt.LK_UNLCK, file_size(f))


# Class for ensuring that all file operations are atomic, treat
# initialization like a standard call to 'open' that happens to be atomic.
# This file opener *must* be used in a "with" block.
class AtomicOpen:
    # Open the file with arguments provided by user. Then acquire
    # a lock on that file object (WARNING: Advisory locking).
    def __init__(self, path, *args, **kwargs):
        # Open the file and acquire a lock on the file before operating
        self.file = open(path,*args, **kwargs)
        # Lock the opened file
        lock_file(self.file)

    # Return the opened file object (knowing a lock has been obtained).
    def __enter__(self, *args, **kwargs): return self.file

    # Unlock the file and close the file object.
    def __exit__(self, exc_type=None, exc_value=None, traceback=None):        
        # Flush to make sure all buffered contents are written to file.
        self.file.flush()
        os.fsync(self.file.fileno())
        # Release the lock on the file.
        unlock_file(self.file)
        self.file.close()
        # Handle exceptions that may have come up during execution, by
        # default any exceptions are raised to the user.
        if (exc_type != None): return False
        else:                  return True
```

Now, `AtomicOpen` can be used in a `with` block where one would normally use an `open` statement.

**WARNINGS:**

- If running on Windows and Python crashes before **exit** is called, I'm not sure what the lock behavior would be.
- The locking provided here is advisory, not absolute. All potentially competing processes must use the "AtomicOpen" class.
- As of (Nov 9th, 2020) this code only locks *writable* files on Posix systems. At some point after the posting and before this date, it became illegal to use the `fcntl.lock` on read-only files.

Comment: `unlock_file` file on linux should not call `fcntl` again with the `LOCK_UN` flag?

Comment: The unlock automatically happens when the file object is closed. However, it was bad programming practice of me not to include it. I've updated the code and added the fcntl unlock operation!

Comment: In `__exit__` you `close` outside of the lock after `unlock_file`. I believe the runtime could flush (i.e., write) data during `close`. I believe one must `flush` and `fsync` under the lock to make sure no additional data is written outside the lock during `close`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I verified that there *is* the possibility for a race condition without the `flush` and `fsync`. I've added the two lines you suggested before calling `unlock`. I re-tested and the race condition appears to be resolved.

Comment: Even if both processes use this, isn't it still possible for things to go wrong if, say, process 2 happens to call `self.file = open('somefile.txt', 'w')`  between process 1's calls to `self.file = open( 'somefile.txt', 'r')` and  `lock_file(self.file)`  ?

Comment: The only thing that will go "wrong" is that by the time process 1 locks the file its contents will be truncated (contents erased). You can test this yourself by adding another file "open" with a "w" to the code above *before* the lock. This is unavoidable though, because you must open the file before locking it. To clarify, the "atomic" is in the sense that only legitimate file contents will be found in a file. This means that you will never get a file with contents from multiple competing processes mixed together.

Comment: According to what I have found via Google, `msvcrt.LK_RLCK` is a read lock, so same as `fcntl.LOCK_SH`, while `msvcrt.LK_LOCK` is the excusive one which is similar to `fcntl.LOCK_EX`.  So you probably must use `msvcrt.LK_LOCK` under Windows.  However the documentation sucks as usual and I have no Windows to verify, sorry.

Comment: So this is a harder problem than expected to address on Windows. The file is locked by a size, but if contents are written then the size changes (and the current code fails on unlock, because the size is wrong). It also appears like the locks are ignored entirely on Windows. I'll have to investigate further, but it will take time. I'll post a solution when I figure it out.

Comment: On Linux it seems, that opening a file for reading throws OSError. As fcntl documentation says: "On at least some systems, LOCK_EX can only be used if the file descriptor refers to a file opened for writing."

Comment: @DeadlyPointer thanks for the catch. I've edited the locking code for systems with `fcntl` to only lock *writeable* files. This appears to be working. However, I haven't tested what happens when files that are being read are modified by another process. I'm not sure how an OS will handle that issue, if anyone wants to contribute their insight or test cases they would be welcome!

Answer (score 44):

There is a cross-platform file locking module here: [Portalocker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/portalocker)

Although as Kevin says, writing to a file from multiple processes at once is something you want to avoid if at all possible.

If you can shoehorn your problem into a database, you could use SQLite.  It supports concurrent access and handles its own locking.

Comment: +1 -- SQLite is almost always the way to go in these kinds of situations.

Comment: Portalocker requires Python Extensions for Windows, on that.

Comment: @naxa there is a variant of it which relies only on msvcrt and ctypes, see http://roundup.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/roundup/roundup/file/tip/roundup/backends/portalocker.py

Comment: @n611x007 Portalocker has just been updated so it doesn't require any extensions on Windows anymore :)

Comment: SQLite supports concurrent access?

Comment: I ended up here because I need a lockfile to repair my SQLite database, which was corrupted by concurrency. I think it's time to burn my computer and become a monk

Comment: Portalocker does not seem work well with nfs mounted files.

Comment: How can we merge `SQLite` into `Python` ?

Answer (score 26):

I have been looking at several solutions to do that and my choice has been
[oslo.concurrency](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/oslo.concurrency/)

It's powerful and relatively well documented. It's based on fasteners.

Other solutions:

- [Portalocker](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/portalocker): requires pywin32, which is an exe installation, so not possible via pip
- [fasteners](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasteners): poorly documented
- [lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile): deprecated
- [flufl.lock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flufl.lock/2.4.1): NFS-safe file locking for POSIX systems.
- [simpleflock](https://github.com/derpston/python-simpleflock) : Last update 2013-07
- [zc.lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.lockfile?) : Last update 2016-06 (as of 2017-03)
- [lock_file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lock_file/2.0) : Last update in 2007-10

Comment: re: Portalocker, you can now install pywin32 through pip via the pypiwin32 package.

Comment: there is also [`filelock`  (Last released: May 18, 2019 at the time of the comment)](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/)

Comment: @jfs isn't `filelock` package same as the accepted answer, where: `pip3 install filelock`

Comment: @alper: same module names, different packages (look at the github)

Comment: @jfs Which one is recommend to use? The `filelock` you linked hase more Star and forks than the accepted answer's package

Comment: @alper pip installs the module I've linked. So it can be considered the default choice unless you have some spry requirements that are better served by some other module.

Answer (score 18):

I prefer **[lockfile](https://github.com/smontanaro/pylockfile)** — Platform-independent file locking

Comment: This library seems well written, but there's no mechanism for detecting stale lock files.  It tracks the PID that created the lock, so should be possible to tell if that process is still running.

Comment: @sherbang: what about [remove_existing_pidfile](https://github.com/smontanaro/pylockfile/blob/master/lockfile/pidlockfile.py#L179)?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen the pidlockfile module doesn't acquire locks atomically.

Comment: @sherbang Are you sure? It opens the lock file with mode O_CREAT|O_EXCL.

Comment: @rgove You're correct, and I misspoke.

Yes, it obtains locks atomically.  What I should have said was that it doesn't allow for an atomic way to deal with stale locks.  Although, I can't recall now if there is a way to handle that atomically.

Comment: Is it possible to get away with the stale locks?

Comment: According to the documentation that packages is deprecated.

Comment: Please note that this library has been superceded and is part of https://github.com/harlowja/fasteners

Answer (score 16):

Locking is platform and device specific, but generally, you have a few options:

1. Use flock(), or equivalent (if your os supports it).  This is advisory locking, unless you check for the lock, it's ignored.
2. Use a lock-copy-move-unlock methodology, where you copy the file, write the new data, then move it (move, not copy - move is an atomic operation in Linux -- check your OS), and you check for the existence of the lock file.
3. Use a directory as a "lock".  This is necessary if you're writing to NFS, since NFS doesn't support flock().
4. There's also the possibility of using shared memory between the processes, but I've never tried that; it's very OS-specific.

For all these methods, you'll have to use a spin-lock (retry-after-failure) technique for acquiring and testing the lock.  This does leave a small window for mis-synchronization, but its generally small enough to not be a major issue.

If you're looking for a solution that is cross platform, then you're better off logging to another system via some other mechanism (the next best thing is the NFS technique above).

Note that sqlite is subject to the same constraints over NFS that normal files are, so you can't write to an sqlite database on a network share and get synchronization for free.

Comment: Note: Move/Rename is not atomic in Win32.  Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows

Comment: New note: `os.rename` is now atomic in Win32 since Python 3.3: https://bugs.python.org/issue8828

Answer (score 10):

Here's an example of how to use the [filelock](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/) library, which is similar to [Evan Fosmark's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/498505):

```py
from filelock import FileLock

lockfile = r"c:\scr.txt"
lock = FileLock(lockfile + ".lock")
with lock:
    file = open(path, "w")
    file.write("123")
    file.close()
```

Any code within the `with lock:` block is thread-safe, meaning that it will be finished before another thread has access to the file.

Comment: This isn't so much adding on to Evan's answer as it is completely orthogonal to it, though you may not have realised that yourself! Somewhat confusingly, the [`filelock`](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/) module on PyPI that you link to in your answer, which like Evan's module exposes a `FileLock` class, is totally unrelated to Evan's work. You can see on GitHub that Evan's code at https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock/blob/master/filelock/filelock.py has no shared code or ancestry with the code at https://github.com/tox-dev/py-filelock/tree/main/src/filelock, which is what you're using here.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't even notice. Thanks for pointing that out, I updated my post accordingly :)

Comment: This is thread safe but not process safe.

Answer (score 7):

Coordinating access to a single file at the OS level is fraught with all kinds of issues that you probably don't want to solve.

Your best bet is have a separate process that coordinates read/write access to that file.

Comment: "separate process that coordinates read/write access to that file" - in other words, implement a database server :-)

Comment: This is actually the best answer. To just say "use a database server" is overly simplified, as a db is not always going to be the right tool for the job. What if it needs to be a plain text file? A good solution might be to spawn a child process and then access it via a named pipe, unix socket, or shared memory.

Comment: -1 because this is just FUD without explanation. Locking a file for writing seems like a pretty straightforward concept to me that OSes offer up with functions like [`flock`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) for it. An approach of "roll your own mutexes and a daemon process to manage them" seems like a rather extreme and complicated approach to take to solve... a problem you haven't actually told us about, but just scarily suggested exists.

Comment: -1 for the reasons given by @Mark Amery, as well as for offering an unsubstantiated opinion about which issues the OP wants to solve

Answer (score 3):

Locking a file is usually a platform-specific operation, so you may need to allow for the possibility of running on different operating systems. For example:

```
import os

def my_lock(f):
    if os.name == "posix":
        # Unix or OS X specific locking here
    elif os.name == "nt":
        # Windows specific locking here
    else:
        print "Unknown operating system, lock unavailable"
```

Comment: You may already know this, but the platform module is also available to obtain information on the running platform. platform.system().
http://docs.python.org/library/platform.html.

Answer (score 2):

I have been working on a situation like this where I run multiple copies of the same program from within the same directory/folder and logging errors.  My approach was to write a "lock file" to the disc before opening the log file. The program checks for the presence of the "lock file" before proceeding, and waits for its turn if the "lock file" exists.

Here is the code:

```
def errlogger(error):

    while True:
        if not exists('errloglock'):
            lock = open('errloglock', 'w')
            if exists('errorlog'): log = open('errorlog', 'a')
            else: log = open('errorlog', 'w')
            log.write(str(datetime.utcnow())[0:-7] + ' ' + error + '\n')
            log.close()
            remove('errloglock')
            return
        else:
            check = stat('errloglock')
            if time() - check.st_ctime > 0.01: remove('errloglock')
            print('waiting my turn')
```

EDIT---
After thinking over some of the comments about stale locks above I edited the code to add a check for staleness of the "lock file."  Timing several thousand iterations of this function on my system gave and average of 0.002066... seconds from just before:

```
lock = open('errloglock', 'w')
```

to just after:

```
remove('errloglock')
```

so I figured I will start with 5 times that amount to indicate staleness and monitor the situation for problems.

Also, as I was working with the timing, I realized that I had a bit of code  that was not really necessary:

```
lock.close()
```

which I had immediately following the open statement, so I have removed it in this edit.

Comment: This won't work always, since some other program can get between `if not exists('errloglock')` and `lock = open('errloglock', 'w')`.

Comment: @RokJaklič You are right if someone writes a program to access the same log file without  checking for the lock file.  You will notice that I qualified the application to "multiple copies of the same program."

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me:
Do not occupy large files, distribute in several small ones
you create file Temp, delete file A and then rename file Temp to A.

```
import os
import json

def Server():
    i = 0
    while i == 0:
        try:        
                with open(File_Temp, "w") as file:
                    json.dump(DATA, file, indent=2)
                if os.path.exists(File_A):
                    os.remove(File_A)
                os.rename(File_Temp, File_A)
                i = 1
        except OSError as e:
                print ("file locked: " ,str(e))
                time.sleep(1)
            
            
def Clients():
    i = 0
    while i == 0:
        try:
            if os.path.exists(File_A):
                with open(File_A,"r") as file:
                    DATA_Temp = file.read()
            DATA = json.loads(DATA_Temp)
            i = 1
        except OSError as e:
            print (str(e))
            time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The **scenario** is like that:
The user requests a file to do something. Then, if the user sends the same request again, it informs the user that the second request is not done until the first request finishes. That's why, I use lock-mechanism to handle this issue.

Here is my working code:

```
from lockfile import LockFile
lock = LockFile(lock_file_path)
status = ""
if not lock.is_locked():
    lock.acquire()
    status = lock.path + ' is locked.'
    print status
else:
    status = lock.path + " is already locked."
    print status

return status
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple and worked(!) [implementation](https://github.com/bmc/grizzled-python/blob/master/grizzled/io/filelock.py) from grizzled-python.

Simple use os.open(..., O_EXCL) + os.close() didn't work on windows.

Comment: O_EXCL option is not related to lock

Answer (score 0):

You may find [pylocker](https://bachiraoun.github.io/pylocker/) very useful. It can be used to lock a file or for locking mechanisms in general and can be accessed from multiple Python processes at once.

If you simply  want to lock a file here's how it works:

```
import uuid
from pylocker import Locker

#  create a unique lock pass. This can be any string.
lpass = str(uuid.uuid1())

# create locker instance.
FL = Locker(filePath='myfile.txt', lockPass=lpass, mode='w')

# aquire the lock
with FL as r:
    # get the result
    acquired, code, fd  = r

    # check if aquired.
    if fd is not None:
        print fd
        fd.write("I have succesfuly aquired the lock !")

# no need to release anything or to close the file descriptor, 
# with statement takes care of that. let's print fd and verify that.
print fd
```

Answer (score -1):

If you just need Mac/POSIX this should work without external packages.

```
import sys
import stat
import os


filePath = "<PATH TO FILE>"
if sys.platform == 'darwin':
  flags = os.stat(filePath).st_flags
  if flags & ~stat.UF_IMMUTABLE:
    os.chflags(filePath, flags & stat.UF_IMMUTABLE)
```

and if you want to unlock a file just change,

```
  if flags & stat.UF_IMMUTABLE:
    os.chflags(filePath, flags & ~stat.UF_IMMUTABLE)
```

Comment: This makes the file immutable, i.e. makes the file unwritable. The question (which mentions multiple processes and writing) is clearly asking about concurrent access with cooperative exclusive locking.

Comment: Hey @neverpanic, yes I see this. I was probably focused on my solution and not the question.