# Python multiple threads accessing same file

Tags: python, file, multithreading

I have two threads, one which writes to a file, and another which periodically
moves the file to a different location. The writes always calls `open` before writing a message, and calls `close` after writing the message. The mover uses shutil.move to do the move.

I see that after the first move is done, the writer cannot write to the file anymore, i.e. the size of the file is always 0 after the first move. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Locking is a possible solution, but I prefer the general architecture of having each external resource (including a file) dealt with by a single, separate thread.  Other threads send work requests to the dedicated thread on a [Queue.Queue](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html?highlight=queue.queue#Queue.Queue) instance (and provide a separate queue of their own as part of the work request's parameters if they need result back), the dedicated thread spends most of its time waiting on a `.get` on that queue and whenever it gets a requests goes on and executes it (and returns results on the passed-in queue if needed).

I've provided detailed examples of this approach e.g. in "Python in a Nutshell".  Python's Queue is intrinsically thread-safe and simplifies your life enormously.

Among the advantages of this architecture is that it translates smoothly to [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=multiprocessing#module-multiprocessing) if and when you decide to switch some work to a separate process instead of a separate thread (e.g. to take advantage of multiple cores) -- `multiprocessing` provides its own workalike `Queue` type to make such a transition smooth as silk;-).

Comment: If I'm writing a library that should be thread-safe but is not always used in threads. Should I take this approach or look at a lock? I'm not sure whether my library should be spawning new threads if it is only being used one thread. What is the best solution for a variable number of threads that could be one?

Answer (score 8):

When two threads access the same resources, weird things happen. To avoid that, always lock the resource. Python has the convenient `threading.Lock` for that, as well as some other tools (see documentation of the `threading` module).

Answer (score 4):

Check out http://www.evanfosmark.com/2009/01/cross-platform-file-locking-support-in-python/

You can use a simple lock with his code, as written by Evan Fosmark in an older StackOverflow question:

```
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("myfile.txt"):
    # work with the file as it is now locked
    print("Lock acquired.")
```

One of the more elegant libraries I've ever seen.

Comment: are you sure this can be actually combined with moving files around?

Comment: Evan Fosmark's code applies to synchronizing multiple *processes*, not *threads*. As per Eli's suggestion, I would use `threading.Lock` or `threading.RLock`.

Comment: As a followup, the link in this post is no longer working. Per [Evan's answer to a related question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/498505/760905) you can also find the code at https://github.com/dmfrey/FileLock