# can python do parallel writing a file without using lock or mutex?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two incoming streaming, both of them are big.
can I flush the first data, let say from the file's position 1 to 512
and the other from 513 to 1023? **Note that** that both streams are coming
**parallelly.**

thanks!

Comment: If concurrency is so vital then why aren't you using mmap?

Comment: Look up the Global Interpreter Lock.  Python doesn't really have concurrency...

Comment: @Endophage: It does as soon as you hit C code, which file I/O is.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams afaik it kind of does when it hits C code.  The file I/O itself is will run concurrently, but if the data is being read into some Python object, that will cause the GIL to kick in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do it. Are you guaranteed correct results? No. Use locks or mmap as suggested by Ignacio.

Here's a good discussion too: [Python multiple threads accessing same file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301458/python-multiple-threads-accessing-same-file)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you mean by parallel, but you can write to two different file objects that have the same file open. I assume it doesn't matter if you are using threads or an event loop.

```
>>> f1 = open("/tmp/foo", "a")
>>> f2 = open("/tmp/foo", "a")
>>> f1.write("a\n")
>>> f2.write("b\n")
>>> f1.close()
>>> f2.close()
>>> print open("/tmp/foo").read()
a
b
```