# FastAPI thread safe file I/O

Tags: python, fastapi

When data is written to a file in FastAPI like below, is this thread safe? Assuming that several requests are sent to the endpoint at the same time.

```
@app.post("/items/")
def add_item(item: str)
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(item + '\n')
    return item
```

And if not, what would be a good way to ensure that each item is written to the file.

Comment: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/876

Comment: Use locking if you want to avoid two processes recreating a file at the same time - or you can use the `append` mode instead of `write` (which truncates the file). Creating files by itself isn't thread safe, unless you implementing locking around the operations you want to perform.

Comment: Best practices from Alex Martelli https://stackoverflow.com/a/2302427/13782669