# Do Django transactions make my non-db operations atomic?

Tags: django, transactions

I have a function that writes file to disk.  Using a concurrent server, it is possible (likely even) that this function could be called by two threads, concurrently.  Looking at the source code, it seems that wrapping my function up in django.db.transaction will keep both my db operations **and** my non-db operations atomic.  Is this correct?

**UPDATE**: What I would really like is not just a yes or no answer but a link to an explanation or a comment on what exactly the thread stuff going on in enter_transaction_management in django.db.transaction.py is doing.

Comment: Looking back at this question, I really needed to qualify the word atomic.  I was more interested in whether or not any django action can happen in between, rather than if something goes wrong will everything get rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "Django transaction", I assume that you mean the transactions in [django.db.transactions](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/)?

And, if that's the case - no. They *only* pertain to database transactions (ie, they will only issue a `BEGIN` then a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`).

Answer (score 0):

NO it won't. Transactions are specific to the database, and are handled much differently than IPC locking.

You should add a process identifier to the file you are writing to to make sure it is unique. Otherwise [lock the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python) to make sure you are the only one writing to it.