# Is this method of file locking acceptable?

Tags: python, linux, networking, locking

We have 10 Linux boxes that must run 100 different tasks each week.  These computers work at these tasks mostly at night when we are at home.  One of my coworkers is working on a project to optimize run time by automating the starting of the tasks with Python.  His program is going to read a list of tasks, grab an open task, mark that task as in progress in the file, and then once the task is finished mark the task as complete in the file.  The task files will be on our network mount.

We realize it is not recommended to have multiple instances of a program accessing the same file, but we don't really see any other option. While he was looking for a way of preventing 2 computers from writing to the file at the same time, I came up with a method of my own, which seemed easier to implement than the methods we found online.  My method is to check if the file exists, wait a few seconds if it doesn't, and then temporarily move the file if it does.  I wrote a script to test this method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time, os, shutil
from shutil import move
from os import path


fh = "testfile"
fhtemp = "testfiletemp"


while os.path.exists(fh) == False:
    time.sleep(3)

move(fh, fhtemp)
f = open(fhtemp, 'w')
line = raw_input("type something: ")
print "writing to file"
f.write(line)
raw_input("hit enter to close file.")
f.close()
move(fhtemp, fh)
```

In our tests this method has worked, but I was wondering if we might have some problems that we aren't seeing by using this.  I realize that disaster could result from two computers running exists() at the same time.  It's unlikely that two computers would get to that point at the same time since the tasks are anywhere between 20 minutes and 8 hours.

Comment: There's *a lot* of race conditions here. Why does 2(or more ?) processes even need to write to the same file ?

Comment: Yes, there is a race condition, hence the attempt to find a solution that won't corrupt the file. Why? Because all the computers need to pull tasks from the same pool and we don't want them running the same task twice.

Comment: So all the tasks are in 1 file ? or 1 file per task ? In any case, take a look at fcntl.lockf() to do file locking, assuming your file share supports them

Comment: Right now they are all on paper.  The idea was to have a file containing the list of tasks with the status, but the tasks themselves are individual scripts.

Comment: Ain't it better to have 1 file per task and the task list to be a folder?

Comment: Yes, it may be.  That was Mark's suggestion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've basically developed a filesystem version of the binary semaphore (or mutex). It's a well-studied structure used for locking, so as long as you get the implementation details right, it should work. The trick is to get the "test and set" operation, or in your case "check existence and move," to be truly atomic. For that I'd use something like this:

```
lock_acquired = False
while not lock_acquired:
    try:
        move(fh, fhtemp)
    except:
        sleep(3)
    else:
        lock_acquired = True
# do your writing
move(fhtemp, fh)
lock_acquired = False
```

The program as you had it would work most of the time, but as mentioned you could have issues if another process moved the file between the check for its existence and the call to `move`. I suppose you could work around that, but I'd personally recommend sticking with a well-tested mutex algorithm. (I've translated/ported the above code sample from *Modern Operating Systems* by Andrew Tanenbaum, but it's possible that I've introduced errors in the conversion - just fair warning)

By the way, the man page for the `open` function on Linux offers this solution for file locking:

> The solution for performing atomic file locking using a lockfile is to create a unique file on the same file system (e.g., incorporating hostname and pid), use link(2)  to make a link to the lockfile. If link() returns 0, the lock is successful. Otherwise, use stat(2) on the unique file to check if its link count has increased to 2, in which case the lock is also successful.

To implement that in Python, you could do something like this:

```
# each instance of the process should have a different filename here
process_lockfile = '/path/to/hostname.pid.lock'
# all processes should have the same filename here
global_lockfile = '/path/to/lockfile'
# create the file if necessary (only once, at the beginning of each process)
with open(process_lockfile, 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n') # or maybe write the hostname and pid

# now, each time you have to lock the file:
lock_acquired = False
while not lock_acquired:
    try:
        link(process_lockfile, global_lockfile)
    except:
        lock_acquired = (stat(process_lockfile).st_nlinks == 2)
    else:
        lock_acquired = True
# do your writing
unlink(global_lockfile)
lock_acquired = False
```

Comment: os.link() is not supported on Windows before Python 3.2. If your code may run on a Windows machine with an earlier version of Python (in addition to Linux or Mac), you could try using a directory as the lockfile. If two processes try to create the directory at the same time, only one will succeed. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/490919/3830997

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me you are putting too much effort to accomplish something that can be simple if you change your data structure. Right now you have a single file that contains list of the tasks.

How about making the task queue a directory instead, where each pending task is a file? Then the process is as easy as picking a task from directory "Pending", *moving* it to directory (say) "Running" and after it is done, move the task file to directory "Completed". Since file move is atomic operation, there will be no race condition (if move fails, means another worker just snatched it first, so pick up next task).

Also, checking the progress is as easy as issuing `ls` on one of the directories :-)

Answer (score 1):

File move/rename is generally an atomic operation on most OSes, so it is probably a workable solution.

You will want to add an exception check on your `move` and `open` calls, though, in case some other process moved the file between your existence check and the `move` (or if the `move` failed to complete).

### Edit

To summarize the proper flow that will work:

1. Issue `move` from A to A.[myID]
2. Try to `open` A.[myID]
3. If #1 or #2 fails, we didn't get the lock; wait a little bit and then go back to #1. Otherwise, we got the lock, continue.
4. Make modifications.
5. Issue `move` from A.[myID] to A. (Should never fail.) This releases the lock.

A good option for `[myID]` is the PID of the process (possibly also include the host, if running on multiple systems).

Comment: Chris: that's why you check on the `open` as well. If the file has been moved, it has been moved to a certain name - thus one process' open will succeed (on the name that it was actually moved to) and the others' will fail (because the file never actually got moved to "their" names).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't track your `move` calls to see if they succeeded or not, you'll never know if you fall victim to a timing window. Remember that if anything can go wrong it will, **at the worst possible time**.

Rather than using the contents of the file as a flag, maybe you could use the filename itself? For each task rename the file "task_waiting_to_run" to "task_running" to "task_complete". If the rename from "task_waiting_to_run" to "task_running" fails, that means another box got there first.

Comment: Since the tasks are in script form, using the names of the scripts as a flag might be a good solution. Thanks.  It would mean making multiple copies of the scripts each week.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: It's also common practice to identify the process that renamed the file. That way, should the process die before restoring it to its original name, it would be possible to trace the file's ownership and determine whether to intervene.

I've inserted (barely tested) `os` and `socket` calls to add this functionality. Use at your own risk.

---

If two processes are competing to rename the file, then having them check for its existence first will not prevent a race condition; it will only delay the time when it occurs.

The docs for [shutil.move](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.move) are (sadly) not explicit about throwing an IOError if the file does not exist, but that seems a reasonable expectation -- and I found it does happen in practice:

```
import shutil
import os
import socket

oldname = "foobar.txt"
newname = (oldname + "." + socket.gethostbyaddr(socket.gethostname())[0]
           + "." + str(os.getpid()))
i_win = True
try:
    shutil.move(oldname, newname)
except IOError, e:
    print "File does not exist"
    i_win = False
except Exception, e:
    print e
    i_win = False

if i_win:
    print "I got it!"
```

This means that only one process can think it has succeeded in renaming the file.

Comment: This is very helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Relying on network filesystems for locking is a problem that has plagued systems for years (and still often doesn't work quite how you expect it)

Why not use something designed to be explicitly multiuser and transactional, like a database system?  (I like Postgres personally...)

It's probably a bit overkill, but the workings are generally easy to understand for something like this.  It also makes it easier to expand to add new functionality later.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a timeout, implemented as a Context Manager so you can use it like this:

```
with NetworkFileLock(r"\\machine\path\lockfile", 60):
```

...

```
@contextmanager
def NetworkFileLock(sharedFilePath, timeoutSeconds):

    # Try to acquire the lock here, by moving the file to a unique path for this process/thread
    uniqueFilePath = "{}-{}-{}-{}".format(sharedFilePath, socket.gethostname(), os.getpid(), threading.get_ident())

    startTime = time.time()
    while True:
        try:
            shutil.move(sharedFilePath, uniqueFilePath)
            # Check temp file now exists
            with open(uniqueFilePath, "r"):
                pass
            break
        except:
            if (time.time() - startTime) > timeoutSeconds:
                raise TimeoutError("Timed out after {} seconds waiting for network lock on file {}".format(time.time() - startTime, networkFilePath))
            time.sleep(3)

    try:
        # Yield to the body of the "with" statement
        yield
    except:
        # Move the file back to release the lock
        shutil.move(uniqueFilePath, sharedFilePath)
        raise
    else:
        # Move the file back to release the lock
        shutil.move(uniqueFilePath, sharedFilePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use [filelock](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/), a cross-platform Python library which barely requires any additional code. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
from filelock import FileLock

line = raw_input("type something: ")
lockfile = "testfile.txt"
lock = FileLock(lockfile + ".lock")
with lock:
    file = open(path, "w")
    file.write(line)
    file.close()
```

Any code within the `with lock:` block is thread-safe, meaning that it will be finished before another process has access to the file.