# How to synchronize processes through a static library on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I have a homework project that require the creation of a STATIC library to provide mutual access to a couple of named pipes.

These pipes are used for communication between various clients using the library and a server.

Now, suppose I want to use pthread mutexes; how can I achieve that? How can the processes know which is the shared memory area in which the mutex is stored? And who should require this memory area?  The server can't because it's required the library itself to provide mutual exclusion.

Thanks to asveikau i came up with this:

```
#define SHARED 1
#define MUTEX 1

int main() {

    sem_t* mutex = sem_open("mutex", O_CREAT);

    sem_init(mutex, SHARED, MUTEX);

    fork(), fork(), fork();

    sem_wait(mutex);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("process %d %d\n", getpid(), i), fflush(stdout);

    sem_post(mutex);
}
```

that from the output really seem to solve my problem.

Thank you to everyone.

Comment: How about posting the text of the homework and what you tried.

Comment: the text of the homework is a 10 pages document written in italian.

Comment: Very closely related to [How to use a file as a mutex in Linux and C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324864/how-to-use-a-file-as-a-mutex-in-linux-and-c/7325044#7325044).  It is not clear that static libraries as opposed to shared libraries are relevant to the problem.

Comment: i think is clear what i need..i need syncronization between clients using the same library..but this library is required to be static

Comment: the project require the use of a static library!

Comment: Note that pthread mutexes are for mutual exclusion amongst the threads of a single process - not for cross-process mutual exclusion.

Comment: The choice between static and dynamic (shared) library is immaterial.  The code can be the same; both will work if the underlying code works.

Comment: You can use named semaphores (`sem_open`) as a cross-process mutex.  Some platforms don't support that though.

Comment: @Banthar i thought about flock!!! in fact i asked about that in another question but everyone said me is not possible to archieve syncronization through flock

Comment: @Jonathan: pthread mutexes can be process-shared (see `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared`) and even *robust* (automatically-unlocking and informing the next thread to obtain the lock when the process that held the lock dies unexpectedly). This makes them a very powerful inter-process synchronization tool!

Comment: @R..: one lives; one learns.  The residual problem is finding a system that supports those functions, but Linux is one such system (MacOS X is not).  Thanks for the information.

Comment: According to the man page of [sem_overview](https://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview), a named semaphore is persistent in the system unless you call sem_unlink(...). Perhaps you should include sem_unlink("mutex") to the end of your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put this down as a comment, but it's worth an answer I think.

As others state, pthread mutexes are not cross-process.  What you need is a "named mutex".  You can use [`sem_open`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_open) to create a cross-process semaphore, and give it an initial count of 1.  In that case `sem_wait` becomes "mutex lock" and `sem_post` becomes "mutex unlock".

Note that `sem_open`, while part of POSIX, is not universally supported.  I believe it works on Linux and Mac OS X.  Probably Solaris if you care about that (these days you probably don't).  I know on OpenBSD it always fails with `ENOSYS`.  YMMV.

Comment: ok we're on the right way. but my problem is: how can different processes be aware of which area the semaphore is stored?