# File Lock in Python

Tags: python, file-locking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Locking a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python)

I want acquire a lock on a file and prevent the writing of this file from other processes. which module and function should I use?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for advisory locking or mandatory locking?