# how can i fix the "ran out of input" error

Tags: pickle

I'm trying to make a listing program for a school assignment where i can add things and delete things from a text document, however i keep running in to this "ran out of input" error that i cant figure out.

all im trying to do is open an empty file that can be edited

```
    mainList = pickle.load(file_handler)
print(mainList)
input()
```

i am then presented with this error:
 mainList = pickle.load(file_handler)
EOFError: Ran out of input

anyone got a good fix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Pickle - EOFError: Ran out of input" reading an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file)