# EOFError Ran out of input

Tags: python, pickle

i get EOFError when i run this cell
anyone here can help me to solve it, please.

```
   pckl_in=open("features.pic","rb")
   feat_xx=pickle.load(pckl_in)
   pckl_target_in=open("target.pic","rb")
   target_yy=pickle.load(pckl_target_in)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Pickle - EOFError: Ran out of input" reading an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file)