# Most efficient way of storing dictionary consisting dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a dictionary that contains dataframes.

```
dictionary = {"key1": df1,
              "key2": df2, and so on...}
```

Few stackoverflow posts and reddit suggests Json module and pickle module.

What would be most efficient way and why?

when I convert small dictionary into pickle it has memory less than 0kb and it renders `EOFError: Ran out of input` which is explained here [Why do I get "Pickle - EOFError: Ran out of input" reading an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file)

Comment: use pickle. you might not be able to store all possible data of the dataframes in a json

Comment: jsonpickle is another alternative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using pickle when you prefer a compact file format.

```
# import packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os

# create dictionary of dataframes
nrows, ncols, ndataframes = 1_000, 50, 100
my_dict = {k:v for (k,v) in [[f'df_{n}', pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(nrows, ncols))] for n in range(ndataframes)]}

# save dictionary as pickle file
pickle_out = open('my_dict.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(my_dict, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

# create new dictionary from pickle file
pickle_in = open('my_dict.pickle', 'rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)

# print file size
print('File size pickle file is', round(os.path.getsize('my_dict.pickle') / (1024**2), 1), 'MB')

# sample
new_dict['df_10'].iloc[:5, :5]
```

Result:

`File size pickle file is 38.2 MB`

```
          0         1         2         3         4
0  0.338838  0.501158  0.406240  0.693233  0.567305
1  0.092142  0.569312  0.952694  0.083705  0.006950
2  0.684314  0.373091  0.550300  0.391419  0.877889
3  0.117929  0.597653  0.726894  0.763094  0.466603
4  0.530755  0.472033  0.553457  0.863435  0.906389
```

Comment: Thanks! I am testing on small dictionary however when in `new_dict = pickle.load(pickle_in)` it gives EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: Can you check if your pickle file is written to disk successfully (and has a file size > 0 bytes).

Comment: When you can share your code, I will have a look. The code in my answer runs without problems on my machine using Python 3.6.9

Comment: I've just created a two dataframe with 3 rows each. Even though it has two 3x5 df it has 0kb.

Comment: Can you add your code to your question. I suspect that reading the pickle fails because saving the pickle file was not successful.

Comment: I just forgot () after pickle_out.close. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative could be the HDFStore which is a dict-like object which reads and writes pandas using the high performance HDF5 format, more details here: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/io.html#hdf5-pytables