# Problem loading ML model saved using joblib/pickle

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pickle, statsmodels, joblib

I saved a jupyter notebook `.pynb` file to `.pickle` format using `joblib.`

My ML model is built using pandas, numpy and the `statsmodels` python library.

I saved the fitted model to a variable called `fitted_model` and here is how I used joblib:

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
# Save RL_Model to file in the current working directory

joblib_file = "joblib_RL_Model.pkl"  
joblib.dump(fitted_model, joblib_file)
```

I get this as output:

```
['joblib_RL_Model.pkl']
```

But when I try to load from file, in a new jupyter notebook, using:

```
# Load from file
joblib_file = "joblib_RL_Model.pkl"  
joblib_LR_model = joblib.load(joblib_file)
joblib_LR_model
```

I only get this back:
**<statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters.HoltWintersResultsWrapper at 0xa1a8a0ba8>**

and no model. I was expecting to see the model load there and see the graph outputs as per original notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use with open, it is better because, it automatically open and close file. Also with proper mode.

```
with open('joblib_RL_Model.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(fitted_model, f)

                                    
with open('joblib_RL_Model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    joblib_LR_model = pickle.load(f)
```

And my implementation in Colab is [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/164_iD21lblkHwSmWGNMwXMQq45QdYx6h?usp=sharing). Check it.

Comment: import library using import pickle

Comment: imported it, the error is now: EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: Check your model if it is blank. For more, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file

Comment: ok, now error is: name 'fitted_model' is not defined

Comment: fitted_model is the desired model that you want to save.

Comment: yes, I made a mistake and had both your commands in the same new file. I now have dump method in original and load in new file. But when I run new file, nothing happens.

Comment: You can share a public Colab file on your work. It will better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220674/discussion-between-cheznead-and-ashraful).

Answer (score 1):

you can use more quantifiable package which is `pickle` default package for python to save models

you can use the the following function for the saving of ML Models

```
import pickle

def save_model(model):
    pickle.dump(model, open("model.pkl", "wb"))
```

template for function would be

```
import pickle

def save_model(model):
    pickle.dump(model, open(PATH_AND_FILE_NAME_TO_BE_SAVED, "wb"))
```

to load the model when saved it from pickle library you can follow the following function

```
def load_model(path):
    return pickle.load(open(path, 'rb'))
```

- Where path is the path and name to file where model is saved to.

Note:

- This would only work for basic ML Models and PyTorch Models, it would not work for Tensorflow based models where you need to use

```
model.save(PATH_TO_MODEL_AND_NAME)
```

where model is of type tensorflow.keras.models

Comment: what would you use then to reload it?

Comment: damn, same error as with the other method. 'ran out of input'. I did this: def load_model():
    pickle.load(open("model.pkl", 'rb')) in new file

Comment: can you please check with the edited answer as i have forgot return in the function, and please do do it like pickle.load(open("./model.pkl", "rb"))