# How to resolve this error "Ran out of input"

Tags: python, ipython, pickle

What could be going wrong with this error: "Ran out of input"

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-9a2c1fe392b0> in <module>
      
pickle_in=open("x.pickle","rb")
x=pickle.load(pickle_in)
pickle_out.close()    
pickle_in=open("y.pickle","rb")

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Pickle - EOFError: Ran out of input" reading an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file)

Comment: Or, if the file is not empty, please show a [mre].