# I am getting the error when I run this code

Tags: python, flask, pickle

***app.py***

In my app.py file, I have written this code to load the model (random_forest_reg_model.pkl):

```
filename = 'random_forest_reg_model.pkl'
model = pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
```

*Error*

Now I am getting this error:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN\anaconda3\envs\carpriceprediction\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:310: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator RandomForestRegressor from version 0.23.2 when using version 0.24.1. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\ML\Projects\CarPricePrediction\app.py", line 10, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open(filename, "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: Where is your `random_forest_reg_model.pkl` file?

Comment: it is in the same directory where my app.py file is saved

Comment: Did you use `wb` when you wrote the pickle?  If it possible you snuck the pickle file into an editor and accidentally changed it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get "Pickle - EOFError: Ran out of input" reading an empty file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file)

Comment: Yes I have used 'wb' :
```import pickle

file = open('random-forest-model.pkl', 'wb')

pickle.dump(rf_random, file)
```

Comment: @BhavikJain `wb` will actually overwrite your file. Try changing it to `rb`

Comment: @Parzival I want to create a new file to export the ML model into it. That is why I am using `wb`.

Even I have done it before but never get this type of error.

Comment: You can check my code here:  [Github](https://github.com/Bhavik-Jain/CarPricePrediction)