# How to solve the problem that my .pkl file will not load

Tags: python, pickle

```
filename = "/content/classifier_10class.pkl"
infile = open(filename,'rb')
new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

---

```
EOFError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-57-36f3a6bd7cfb> in <module>()

      1 filename = "/content/classifier_10class.pkl"
      2 infile = open(filename,'rb')
 ---> 3 new_dict = pickle.load(infile)
      4 infile.close()

EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791987/why-do-i-get-pickle-eoferror-ran-out-of-input-reading-an-empty-file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try following code ?

```
>>> import pickle
>>> with open('file.pkl', 'rb') as fp:
>>>     data = pickle.load(fp)
```