# EOFError when trying to load large dictionary using cPickle

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, eoferror

I'm trying to load two large dictionaries that I pickled earlier using cPickle. Here's the code that I used to create the pickle:

```
f_out = open("file_1.pickle", 'wb')
cPickle.dump(obj_1, f_out, protocol=-1)
f_out.close()
f_out = open("file_2.pickle", 'wb')
cPickle.dump(obj_2, f_out, protocol=-1)
f_out.close()
```

`f_out` is not used anywhere else in the script that creates the dictionaries, and the script ran without errors. The pickles are large: 895.9 MB for `obj_1` and 978.3 MB for `obj_2`. The files have been renamed, but not altered in any other way. The following code is used to load the pickles:

```
f1 = open("file_1_renamed.pickle", 'rb')
obj_1 = cPickle.load(f1)
f1.close()
f2 = open("file_2_renamed.pickle", 'rb')
obj_2 = cPickle.load(f2)
f2.close()
```

`obj_1` loads without issues, but trying to load `obj_2` creates an `EOFError`. I get the same error with `pickle.load()` and also when I open the file as text, not as binary. Another question on Stack Overflow ([Python Pickling Dictionary EOFError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263564/python-pickling-dictionary-eoferror)) suggests that this might be related to insufficient memory, and but I'm not entirely convinced – why would a memory issue lead to an end-of-file error? I'm using OS X 10.9.5 and Python 2.7.8.