# Check if Python program is running, in Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am in the process of creating a Python program (lets call it Program1), which will terminate randomly. I need another program to check if Program1 has been terminated, and if so, to restart it after a given amount of time. Should I use another Python program to do this, or is there a way this can be done in Windows e.g. similar to a cron job?

From what I understand, you can use sys.exit(), exit() and quit() to kill a Python program, but do all of these also kill all other running Python programs?

Thanks

Comment: *do all of these also kill all other running Python programs?* they all do not

Answer (score 1):

Reliably determining whether a specific program is still running or not can be done in multiple ways.

A good way to do so would be using a specific lock file. You can find how to do this in Python described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python).

To answer the second part of your question: `sys.exit()`, `exit()` and others will only stop the currently running Python process, not any others that might be running concurrently.