# Is there a way to prevent two Python programs from executing the same binary at the same time?

Tags: python, race-condition

I have two Python scripts, that both need at regular intervals (think cronjobs) to call an external program.

If this program (over which we have no control) is called twice simultaneously, data errors occur, so we need to have a way to synchronize calls to this binary.

Is there a way to do this, preferably using only the Python standard library?

Comment: Just use a file based lock that each script checks for before executing the external binary.

Comment: If the program is external, both scripts could share a simple "lock" file.

Comment: I don't *think* there is a ready-to-use solution in the stdlib; but there is [lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So without using a 3rd-party library such as [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock) you'll have to do something like this:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call

if os.path.exists("/var/run/foo.ock"):
    print("Backing off...")
    raise SystemExit(1)

try:
    with open("/var/run/foo.lock", "w"):
        check_call("/path/to/binary")
finally:
    os.remove("/var/run/foo.lock")
```

The better approach is to use [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock) (*if you can install 3rd party libraries*):

```
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("/path/to/binary"):
    check_call("/path/to/binary")
```

You can *easily* install [filelock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/filelock) using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io):

```
$ pip install filelock
```

See also related: [Locking a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python)

**Note:** There also seems to be a *very similarly* named package called [lockfile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lockfile)! (*Don't confuse the two!*)