# How to safely write to the same file from two threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, file, pyqt

Here is the context: I made a Qt5 program to drive a sourcemeter, it applies an electrical signal to a sample and measures its reaction, plotting data to matplotlib in real time. It looks like this: [image]

Plotting is done by the main thread, measuring/applying is done in another thread so that display does not slow down measurements.

The program also has a button to take all the available data from the plot and store it in a .csv file, but I'm considering having it write the values one by one in real time instead. I would like to add an optional input for the user to add description, so the stored data would be the actual I/V/time columns sometimes interrupted by text like "t=60, the sample smells funny". Writing the description line to the file would be easy, it's just a push button connected to a tiny function. The problem is that my file is already open somewhere else. **Is that a problem at all?**, I actually don't know, and if yes:

**How do I safely write this additional description text from the main thread, while the file is opened by the measurements thread?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it a single file handle shared by both threads? If so, a lock should work.

Comment: Yes it's a single file that is shared. Ok thanks for the info. I am starting to read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python, but is there a lock library in particular that you would advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Open the file in your main thread
- Pass the file handle to your other thread
- In each thread, always lock before writing to the file

Comment: Cheers! Any locking library your would recommend in particular?

Comment: Look up `threading.Lock()`, also look at the linked question