# How to lock file from write operations of other applications in operating system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, locking

I have a file. My application must open it and protect it from writing done by other applications in my operating system.

Is it possible to do such thing? I tried fcntl.flock() but it seems that this lock is working only for my application. Other programs like text editors can write to file without any problems.

Test example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time
import fcntl

with open('./somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    # accquire lock
    fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)

    # some long running operation
    # file should be protected from writes
    # of other programs on this computer
    time.sleep(20)

    # release lock
    fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
```

How can I lock a file for every application in system except mine?

Answer (score 0):

Flock is advisory locking and it's ignored unless specifically checked for.

There are other alternatives that does mandatory locking [like this one.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140531203736/http://www.evanfosmark.com:80/2009/01/cross-platform-file-locking-support-in-python/)
Found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python/498505) and there are some more alternatives in there as well.

Comment: It seems that any of those links does not contain "mandatory locking", all they just adding cross platform functionality but they all are still advisory file locking methods.