# Python locking and unlocking file from multiple processes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file `xxx.txt` that is accessed by other Python files. When `script_1` is about to write to `xxx.txt` it should lock the file and `script_2` should wait until the file is released by `script_1`.

I tried using this code but it does not lock the file. `script_2` was able to write the file.

```
import fcntl, os, signal, time


os.fork()

class TimeoutException(Exception): pass

def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException()


f = os.open("xxx.txt", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREAT)
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX)
time.sleep(20)
os.write(f, bytes("oook_0", "utf-8"))
fcntl.flock(f, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
os.close(f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ok first, locking a file is a platform-specific operation, so you will need to run different code for different operating systems.
2. Secondly, as @Kevin said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python), - "coordinating access to a single file at the OS level is fraught with all kinds of issues that you probably don't want to solve. Your best bet is have a separate process that coordinates read/write access to that file."

Answer (score 0):

Solved with

```
from filelock import FileLock

with FileLock("lock"):
    with open('lock', mode='w') as file:
        file.write('oook_1')
```