# How to read and write the same file at a time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

There are three python programs, writer program `(writer.py)` writes in to the file `output.txt` and two reader programs `(reader_1.py, reader_2.py)` read from the same `output.txt file` at a same time.

**What is the best way to achieve the synchronization between these three programs?**
  How to avoid reading by the reader program, if the other program is writing in to the output file?
  **How to handle single writer and multiple readers problem efficiently in python?**

I tried to implement the fnctl locking mechanism, but this module is not found in my python.

**writer.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import time

cycle = 10

cmd="ls -lrt"

def poll():
   with open("/home/output.txt", 'a') as fobj:
      fobj.seek(0)
      fobj.truncate()
      try:
          subprocess.Popen(cmd,  shell=True,  stdout=fobj)
      except Exception:
          print "Exception Occured"

# Poll the  Data
def do_poll():
    count = int(time.time())

    while True:

        looptime = int(time.time())

        if (looptime - count) >= cycle:
             count = int(time.time())
             print('Begin polling cycle')
             poll()
             print('End polling cycle')

def main():
    do_poll()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**reader_1.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("/home/output10.txt", 'r') as fobj:
   f=fobj.read()

print f
```

**reader_2.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

with open("/home/output10.txt", 'r') as fobj:
   f=fobj.read()

print f
```

Note: **reader_1.py and reader_2.py runs continuously in while loop.**
       Due to this reason same file being accessed by three programs at same time.

Looking for ideas.

Solution #1: Added fnctl locking mechanism to writer.py program. But not sure this is efficiently locking the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import time
import os
import fcntl, os

report_cycle = 2

cmd='ls -lrt'

def poll(devnull):
   with open("/home/output10.txt", 'a') as fobj:
      try:
         fcntl.flock(fobj, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)
      except IOError:
          print "flock() failed to hold an exclusive lock."

      fobj.seek(0)
      fobj.truncate()

      try:
         subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True,  stdout=fobj, stderr=devnull)
      except Exception:
          print "Exception Occured"

      # Unlock file
      try:
           fcntl.flock(fobj, fcntl.LOCK_UN)
      except:
            print "flock() failed to unlock file."
```

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Linux (centos )

Comment: `fcntl` is part of the base `cpython` on centos. Its a compiled C module. Are you using some other system? Perhaps you have a virtualenv that hasn't mapped it over?

Comment: Python version is 2.7, I am working on a physical system not in any virtual environment.    cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)
[root]# python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug  7 2019, 00:51:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import fnctl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fnctl

Comment: Spelling?! `fcntl`.

Comment: When i imported as "import fcntl, os" , no error is seen.

Comment: Nice. Just `import fcnt` fails, though? `os` is imported by python itself (`"os" in sys.modules.keys()`) so it shouldn't have any role here. But if it works...

Comment: Waiting for ideas

Comment: Was there an answer for this? Not able to see anything that clearly states what the solution is

Comment: Have you tried any of the libraries mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python ?