# How to clear a file that is being used in a script and always writing on it? Strange symbols appear

Tags: python

I got a python script in `crontab` writing in a file 24/7 because is always getting information and writing on file FILE.txt.

I run another script on `crontab` to get that content and send to a database (just what I want) and then truncate file.

But what happen? Lets suppose the file have **1000 bytes** and I clear with that second script, the file after writing on it will have **1000 bytes + new bytes.**

That **1000 bytes** are strange symbols on file something like `(?)(?)(?)(?)(?)`

I tried the following:

```
file.seek(0)
file.truncate(0)
```

But without success.

Comment: Are you truncating file which is still open in another process?

Comment: You really shouldn't edit file concurrently that will always cause problems.

Comment: @Alex yes, its opened in another screen.

Comment: @miszcz2137 how should I do this then? :/

Comment: Your "24/7" script should coordinate with your "log-rotation" script.

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python

Comment: Also not even if you fix this more efficient would be if both task aren't scheduled at the same time (for example do one at full hour, other five past full hour)

Comment: I think this question needs some clarification. A cron script is run periodically. IMO it cannot be "always writing".

Comment: Crontab *@reboot screen -dmS bTCP; sleep 5; screen -S bTCP -X stuff '/usr/sbin/tcpdump -i any port 3306 -s 65535 -x -nn -q -tttt> /path/to/tcpdump_3306.out\n'* @VPfB

Comment: That will run a new screen with that, always writing. Then I use **0 12 * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/scripts/test.py**

Comment: @HenriqueMota Thank you for adding the information about ``@reboot`` cron extension. I think the design with one ever increasing file is very disadvantageous. I don't know an answer for the general case as in the question title (how to clear a file ...), but I think, there is a solution. The ``tcpdump`` can do some *raw* data file rotation. See the man page, options ``-w raw-data-file`` , ``-G rorate-seconds``, and ``-z postrotate-command ``. Also ``-r`` for reading the saved file in the postrotate-command. Hope this helps.