# How to check whether a file I want to open in my python 3.x program, is already opened by another program in windows?

Tags: python-3.x

I have made two python scripts. One will run always, another one will run when I start it. Suppose program A runs all time. I insert some information to a file through program B. Program A will check that file after some time and do the works according to instruction. I want to prevent the deadlock or dirty rear situation.

When I shall give input to the file, then program A will be unable to read that file. How can I do this in Python 3?

Comment: You can use a [File Lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python) by both programs to prevent simulations access.

Comment: @Obenland thank you :)