# How can I prevent the filename from changing (rename) using python?

Tags: python, rename, block

I have a project in mind, but there is a section that I don't know how to do. I'm using Python version 3.6 and windows 10. For example we have a file name of "example.txt" I want to prevent the name and its content of this file from being changed.

I did research on this topic, but I could not reach any research. Can we prevent the file's name (including its extension) from changing or its contents?To realize this, I think it is necessary to start as an administrator.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give some more details? -What might you be doing that could change the file?

Comment: To prevent programs such as ransomware from making changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to stop another program from editing a file by locking it in python.

There is a module that does this called [filelock](https://pypi.org/project/filelock/). Take a look at the source code to see how it is done.

It is also worth noting that more [advanced ransomware](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/sodinokibi-ransomware-can-now-encrypt-open-and-locked-files/) will try to stop processes so they can encrypt files, so this might not work in all cases.

Comment: This question has more details too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python