# How To Lock Files Using Python

Tags: python, cmd, operating-system

I am working on some project.

I want that I **lock some file** whenever I run the script.

So that noone can ***delete/modify*** the file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Locking a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python)

Comment: To lock a file you specify a sharemode. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-programming-on/1565926218/re32.html

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew . The first link is totally stupid answers. **sharemode**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **os module** for this purpose.

```
import os
file_path = 'D:\\file.txt'    # your file path
os.system(f'echo y| cacls {file_path} /P everyone:n')
```

I hope you got it.