# How to Rename a jar file from java program ?or any other way from Command promt?

Tags: java

I am working on Application that is downloading certain jars from web server like RMTcmark.jar,RMProduct.jar,RMLatency.jar,all RM named jars.These jars are getting stored in some Directory .But These RM named files not workable for me,

I want Only file name i.e RM should be Removed from the name of that file for instance if a file name is RMTcmark.jar ---->Tcmark.jar
             RMProduct.jar---->Product.jar,in this way

Is there any way out in java to Rename such jar files?

Also ,My second question is ,there are similar files named as RTPostMark.jar,RTLatency are getting downloaded from web server ,all of size 1 kb,

I want all this RT Named jars should get Deleted from the directory where they are getting stored.

If not possible from java,cn we do it from command promt ??

Comment: By command prompt, are you referring to Linux, Windows, Macintosh? Also, read up on Java's [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) documentation.

Comment: i am using Windows ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename the file using java

Refer links below

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-rename-file-in-java/

[Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java)

The logic which you should work is to parse the files and if the file is starting with the name "RM" then for the new file name, you will have to exclude the name RM and then create file object as suggested in the links

Comment: But how to delete files name as RT whose size is 1 kb ,can we delete such files based on size in java??

Comment: Ya you can do that. And if my answer is working. Please mark the same as correct answer :)

Comment: use `length()` method in `File` class . With this you can get the file's size. For more info, Please refer this API link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html