# File name changer program - need to save file name into a string

Tags: java, string, text, filenames

```
package javaapplication6;
import java.util.*;

public class JavaApplication6{

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner vh=new Scanner(System.in);

    String niz="";

    char pod_niz=vh.next().charAt(0);
    char pod_niz2=vh.next().charAt(0);

        int index=niz.indexOf(pod_niz);

                String m=niz.replace(niz.charAt(index),pod_niz2);


            System.out.println(m);
}
}
```

So this program changes one letter from a string.So for example:

```
String niz="monkey";
char pod_niz='y';
char pod_niz='x';
```

I get monkex

Now i have a file (D:\file.bin) and i want to change it to File.bin using this program.
How to do that?
Maybe I need to store the file name into a String, change it, then change the file name using the data which the String contains.

Thanks..

Comment: I guess this has the answer you are looking for: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java

Comment: Maybe you're right. Have you tried it that way?

Comment: i think this can't help me..

Comment: How do you intend to use this program? Do you expect the user to enter the name of the file or is it hard-coded? Should it apply the rename in all the files in a folder? On that depends what solution you need.

Comment: actually i need a program that will read all the files in a directory,enter 2 letters and if some file contains the first letter it must change it to the second one( like the example i gave ).But for now i need just for one file.