# Add extension to File

Tags: java, file

I have a File named `myfile` without extension. I want to add an extension to it so it will be `myfile.ext`. I don't want to open it and save it with an extension. Just "rename" the File class instance.
How can I do it?

P.S. If that matters, I need this because I want to use this:

```
    File myfiletopeon=myfile;
    if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        try {
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(myfiletopeon);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Problem","Problem",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

in order to open the file and I need an extension so that the file can be opened

Comment: In Java 7 you can use this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29

Comment: Just googled "java rename" and got this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java Please search before asking.

Comment: Just rename it with extension

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo(java.io.File)

Comment: You have to rename the actual file (e.g. `File#rename()`) because the program opening the file can't see that name if the name exists just within your program.

Comment: Please do a little searching in google before posting a question here, It might have already been answered.

Comment: ok, ok don't hit :) I had in mind there might be a special method that add extensions (=strings) to File names. The solution is              `String newFilePath = myfile.getAbsolutePath().replace(myfile.getName(), myfile.getName()+".ext") ;` and then get the new File 
             `File newFile = new File(newFilePath); `

Answer (score 1):

How about using `File.renameTo()` method?