# Save as java file

Tags: java, io

I have a

```
 File file = new File("/home/aa.db");
```

then I call `file.delete();`

but I like to save this file before delete with the other name in the other location. - how it is possible to do in code without any visual tools?

I need a copy - because I need to remove init file. Renaming will not do the thing

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy

Comment: Why not just rename it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java

Comment: I have add import nio.file; than I try file. (but there is no copy) than I wrote java.nio.file. (but there is no copy as static method here too) =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the sample of moving file to new directory -

```
File file = new File("/home/aa.db");
File dir = new File("dir");

if (file.renameTo(new File(dir, file.getName()))) {
    // processing here
}
```

---

Relevant example:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File file = new File("C://aa.db");
        File tmpFile = new File("C://temp", file.getName());

        if(file.renameTo(tmpFile)) {
            if(tmpFile.delete()) {
                System.out.println(tmpFile.getName() + " was deleted!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Delete operation failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
`aa.db was deleted!`

Answer (score -1):

Read the data of file(your need) in `InputStream` and then use this function of `File`

```
public static long copy(InputStream in,Path target,CopyOption... options)
                 throws IOException
```

> Copies all bytes from an input stream to a file. On return, the input
>   stream will be at end of stream.

Before this, first you need to create the target path where you want to copy the data.