# Fetching a file sequentially removing timestamp

Tags: java

I have the same name csv files appened with Timestamp at server. I want to copy one file at a time, removing the timestamp to another location.
For example the files are present as under at the server:
MyFile_20140226.csv
MyFile_20140227.csv
MyFile_20140228.csv

I need to copy one file at a time removing the timestamp from the name of file as MyFile.csv to another location.

How should I get the filename sequentially removing the timestamp in java.

Comment: When you say `timestamp`, do you mean the numbers in the file name?  (ex.  `20140226` in `MyFile_20140226.csv `)?  Also what have you tried?

Comment: Writing the code for that from scratch in an answer would be a bit much. Please share with us what you already have.

Comment: do you also here that shouting? "use bash, use bash, use bash..." :)

Answer (score 0):

You could just rename the file.  When you rename it, you can also change the directory it's in.  This would essentially move and rename the file:

```
if(new File("C:\\old\\path\\" + "MyFile_20140226.csv").renameTo(new File("C:\\new\\path\\" + "MyFile.csv"))
    System.out.println("File is moved successful!");
else
    System.out.println("File is failed to move!");
```

[Source 1](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-move-file-to-another-directory-in-java/)

[Source 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java)

**NOTE 1**:  There are better, cleaner, and safer ways to do this.  Look at the sources.  I just wanted to give some minimal example.

**NOTE 2**:  I would highly recommend doing some research yourself (use Google).  There are many examples online.