# Rename all files in a folder using java

Tags: java, file, directory, rename

How can we rename all files in a folder using java?

```
C:/temp/pictures/1.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/2.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/3.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/4.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/5.jpg
```

Rename to

```
C:/temp/pictures/landscape_1.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/landscape_2.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/landscape_3.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/landscape_4.jpg
C:/temp/pictures/landscape_5.jpg
```

Kind regards

Comment: you can find it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java

Comment: You can find another clear example [here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/io/RenameFileOrDir.shtml)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take a look at below code which check file in the folder and rename it.

```
File dir = new File("D:/xyz");

if (dir.isDirectory()) { // make sure it's a directory
    for (final File f : dir.listFiles()) {
        try {
            File newfile =new File("newfile.txt");

            if(f.renameTo(newfile)){
                System.out.println("Rename succesful");
            }else{
                System.out.println("Rename failed");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I Hope It Will Help You