# Rename Android Folder on code

Tags: java, android, rename

I want change Folder name with java code in android.
for example :
change "Picture" Folder name to "MyPicture"
Please Help me.
thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename all files in a folder using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199679/rename-all-files-in-a-folder-using-java)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to change programatically a folder´s name use the `renameTo()` method:

```
File oldFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"old folder name");
File newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"new folder name");
boolean success = oldFolder.renameTo(newFolder);
```

Here you can find info about `renameTo()` method : 
**http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto.htm**

Comment: thank you.but it dosnt worked for me. for example My Folder Name Is "New Folder" And I want change it to "New Foder3" .                             File oldfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"New Folder");
   File newfolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"New Folder3");
   oldfolder.renameTo(newfolder);

Comment: well "path" supposed to be the path where your folder is located.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `renameTo()` method:

```
File oldfolder = new File("path of the old folder","old name");
File newfolder = new File("path of the new folder","new name");
oldfolder.renameTo(newfolder);
```