# moving files into different directory using file names from stored arraylist

Tags: java

i've searched a keyword "MISSING RESIDUES" from files in a directory and stored the file names in Arraylist. now i want to move those filtered file names from this directory to another. can anybody help me with that?

```
public class Filter_missingres_files {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    File dir = new File("D:\\iso_upd"); // directory = target directory.
    if(dir.exists()) // Directory exists then proceed.
    { 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("MISSING RESIDUES"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of files.

        for(File f : dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(!f.isFile()) continue;
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                    byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                    fis.read(data);
                    String text = new String(data);
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                    if(m.find())
                    {
                        list.add(f.getName()); // add file to found-keyword list.
                    }
                    fis.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\t Error processing file : "+f.getName());
                }

        }
    System.out.print("\n\t List : "+list); // list of files containing keyword.
    } // IF directory exists then only process.
            else
        {
            System.out.print("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
        }
}
```

}

Comment: my answer help you? If yes, please, mark the response as "accepted".

Answer (score 1):

For each file, uses Files.move:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        Files.move(new File("fileName").toPath(), new File("newDirectory/fileName").toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
```

Comment: While `new File("fileName").toPath()` instead of `Paths.get("fileName)`? Why `new File("newDirectory/fileName").toPath()` instead of `Paths.get("newDirectory/fileName")`? Better yet, why not just have a `Paths.get("newDirectory")` and use `.resolve()`?

Comment: Also, uh, well, why not just use a `Files.newDirectoryStream()` with an appropriate `DirectoryStream.Filter<Path>`?

Comment: @fge, any specific reason for "new File().toPath". Both ways gets a Path. I confess that its format is more elegant, but usually for those who are not familiar with NIO2 is less obvious.

Comment: there IS a difference between `new File(...).toPath()` and `Paths.get()`. Subtle but which may be important...

Comment: The first, and obvious difference, is that a `File` can only refer to `Path`s issued from the default filesystem; the other and much less obvious one is that an fs entry is ultimately a sequence of bytes, not chars; which means the encoding matters. And while `File` is oblivious about encoding impossibilities, `Path` is not. [Demonstration](http://pastie.org/10026850).

Answer (score 0):

try that, instead to store the file name, store the file object, and then for each file stored, move to a new destination.
myFile.renameTo(new File("/the/new/place"));

```
  // TODO code application logic here
    File dir = new File("D:\\iso_upd"); // directory = target directory.
    if(dir.exists()) // Directory exists then proceed.
    { 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("MISSING RESIDUES"); // keyword = keyword to search in files.
        ArrayList<File> list = new ArrayList<File>(); // list of files.

        for(File f : dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(!f.isFile()) continue;
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
                byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
                fis.read(data);
                String text = new String(data);
                Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
                if(m.find())
                {
                        list.add(f); // add file to found-keyword list.
                    }
                    fis.close();
                } 
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    System.out.print("\n\t Error processing file : "+f.getName());
                }

            }

        }  
    String detinationPath= "D:\\destinationdir"
    File destinatiorDir = new File(detinationPath); // directory = destination directory.
    if(destinatiorDir.exists()) // Directory exists then proceed.
    { 
       for(File f :list ){
        f.renameTo(new File(detinationPath+ f.getName()));
    }
}else{
    System.out.print("\n Directory doesn't exist.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

// File (or directory) with old name
    File file = new File("oldname");

```
// File (or directory) with new name
File file2 = new File("newname");
if(file2.exists()) throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

// Rename file (or directory)
boolean success = file.renameTo(file2);
if (!success) {
    // File was not successfully renamed
}
```

Copied from [Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/renaming-a-file-using-java)

Comment: `File`'s `.renameTo()` is unreliable. It returns `false`; OK. Then what is the error?