# How do I rename a file in Scala?

Tags: scala

I want to rename a file in the system by Scala code. The equivalent of what can be done by bash like,

```
mv old_file_name new_file_name
```

I am not asking about renaming a scala source code file, but a file residing in the system.

Comment: The same as in Java.

Comment: [Rename a file using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider

```
import java.io.File
import util.Try

def mv(oldName: String, newName: String) = 
  Try(new File(oldName).renameTo(new File(newName))).getOrElse(false)
```

and use it with

```
mv("oldname", "newname")
```

Note `mv` returns `true` on successful renaming, `false` otherwise. Note also that `Try` will catch possible IO exceptions.

Comment: You are totally ignoring the return value of `renameTo`. In other words, whenever `renameTo` just returns `false` (indicating that it could not rename the file) instead of throwing an exception, `mv` will return `true` anyway, as if the operation had succeeded (when it did not). You should replace `.isSuccess` with `getOrElse(false)`.

Answer (score 6):

See `renameTo` of `java.io.File`. In your case this would be

```
new File("old_file_name").renameTo(new File("new_file_name"))
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the target path is on different drive.

Answer (score 1):

Use Guava:

```
Files.move(new File("<path from>"), new File("<path to>"))
```