# Reading a compressed CSV file from S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3

I'm supposed to read thousands of *.CSV files from S3 using Spark. These files have `Content-Encoding` of `gzip` as metadata in their properties. Normally I do:

```
sqlContext.read.csv("s3a://bucket/file.csv")
```

But that doesn't work in this case as the files are compressed. If I could change the extension of the file it would work (but I have no control over that):

```
sqlContext.read.csv("s3a://bucket/file.csv.gz")
```

I'm aware of [this method](http://arjon.es/2015/10/02/reading-compressed-data-with-spark-using-unknown-file-extensions/) to register file extensions as compressed files but adding .csv as a compressed extension is problematic for normal CSV files.
Is there any way to force Spark to decompress CSV files without adding .csv as a compressed format?

Comment: perhaps decompress as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436549/uncompress-and-read-gzip-file-in-scala then `parallelize`?

Comment: or to rename the files https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30614443/how-do-i-rename-a-file-in-scala

Comment: @JoelBerkeley I have no control over the name of the files. Regarding decompress using Scala: I have thousands of files to read and it takes too much effort to make sure reading and decompressing those files doesn't clog the resources.