# RENAMING a file in java

Tags: java

I am using the following code but I am not able to rename the file.There is no such file `newname.txt` in the system as well. I am using JRE6. Please help me out! Also I have tried to rename using Files class, That too isn't working.

```
File f1 = new File("oldname.txt");
File f2 = new File("newname.txt");
boolean b = f1.renameTo(f2);
```

The same code gets execute on SunOs UNIX but not on my windows 7. Why is it so ? Can I do something to execute it on my local machine?

Comment: Is there a file `oldname.txt`? Are you ***sure***?

Comment: Maybe try println-ing "f1.exists()" to see if you have a handle to the original first?

Comment: Yeah oldname.txt is there ... @ElliottFrisch

Comment: @billjamesdev .. It actually exists, Moreover the code runs fine on another machine

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java

Comment: what is the error/problem you are facing? does the `oldname.txt` exists in the system directory?

Comment: down voter reason??

Answer (score 0):

File path to oldname.txt is not correct, Try giving the absolute path and check it works like "c:\oldname.txt"

`File f1 = new File("c:\\oldname.txt");
File f2 = new File("c:\\newname.txt");
boolean b = f1.renameTo(f2);`

at the end print the value of b

Answer (score 0):

Ref: [Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java)   (edited little bit to fit your requirment)

```
File f1 = new File("oldname.txt");
File f2 = new File("newname.txt");

if (!f1.exists())
       throw new java.io.FileNotFoundException("file not found");   
if (f2.exists())
   throw new java.io.IOException("file exists");

// Rename file (or directory)
boolean success = f1.renameTo(f2);

if (!success) {
   // File was not successfully renamed
}
```