# Use JGit to rename the repository

Tags: rename, jgit

I'm developing a tool that has 3 functions as follows:

- Create a Git repository.
- Delete a Git repository.
- Rename a Git repository.

I must use JGit to implement this tool. But I did not find a way to rename of the repository by using JGit.

Does anyone know how to use JGit to rename the repository?

Comment: I ticked. Thank you for your instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Git repository does not have a name in itself, hence JGit does not provide an API for renaming.

Usually the last segment of the directly in which the repository is located is used to name it when necessary. For example a repository in `/foo/bar/.git` will be named `bar`.

In order to rename a repository, simply [move its location by using the Java file API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20260300/2986905).

Comment: Thank you so muck. I understand.