# How to create log file with date time name format (05_10_2018 02_24_45_automation.log) in log4j java

Tags: java, log4j

I want to create a log file with date time name on every execution. We are using LOG4J (JAVA) to create the logs in our program.
Whenever we execute the program it should append the current date and time with a file name and save.

```
    e.g. 

     file format {dd-MM-yyyy hh_mm_ss}_Automation.log

        Folder: logs/..
            05_10_2018 02_24_45_Automation.log 
            05_10_2018 02_26_45_Automation.log 
            05_10_2018 02_28_45_Automation.log 
            05_10_2018 02_30_45_Automation.log 
            05_10_2018 02_32_45_Automation.log
```

Configuration:

```
   <appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a} %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="logs/log.log" />
        <param name="immediateFlush" value="true" />
        <param name="threshold" value="debug" />
        <param name="append" value="false" />

        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a} %-5p - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

Whenever program executes it should append the date time with file name. I don't want to split the file in multiple files as RollingAppender does.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rename a file using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java)

Comment: Tip: Reversing the order makes your file names list sorted in chronological order: year-month-day-hour-minute-second.