# Can't change Java file permissions

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin

I'm working with Files in Kotlin and Java and can't change the permission are do anything with them at all really. I'm thinking it's from a lack of understanding of how they work.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
   val file1 = File("Hello.txt")
   val file2 = File("Hello2.txt")

   if (file1.renameTo(file2)) {
       println("rename succeeded")
   } else {
       println("rename failed")
   }

   if(file1.setReadable(true, true)) {
       println("readable succeeded")
   } else {
    println("readable failed")
   }
}
```

I create the files and it fails both when I try to rename, and when I try to set to readable.

I have a much larger project where I'm creating them by reading from a usb, saving them to a temporary location, and attempting to do the same thing. Figured I'd start with the smaller more easily reproducible example.

Is there anything I have to configure to make both of these files readable?

Comment: "I'm creating them by reading from a usb" -- you do not have access to arbitrary files on [removable storage in Android](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/15/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Answer (score 1):

If a file named `Hello2.txt` is already present in the location then you won't be able to rename `Hello.txt` to `Hello2.txt`.

The first line of code for rename works if there is no file name conflict.

Comment: based on a few different examples on renaming files online, that should work `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java`

Why would it affect being able to set it as readable as well?

Comment: you are not checking for `Hello2.txt` existance

Comment: and setReadable is dependent on system for permissions