# File is not renamed

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to implement this Spring endpoint:

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "/opt/";

@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<StringResponseDTO> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("id") Integer merchant_id) throws Exception {

        InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();

        try {
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();

            File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER, merchant_id.toString());
            directory.mkdirs();
            File newFile = new File(directory, file.getOriginalFilename());
            newFile.renameTo(new File("merchant_logo.png"));
            Files.write(newFile.toPath(), bytes);

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "You successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new StringResponseDTO(originalName));
    }
```

The general idea is to rename the file and override previous file with the same name. But for some reason it's not working. I get the old file content. Any idea why?

Comment: `renameTo` probably won't work if the target file already exists, try deleting it first.

Comment: When you are renaming the file, try to keep the correct file path with the new name in the `renameTo` method

Comment: Probably yes, is there some other way to rename a file?

Comment: @mnestorov can you show me code example please?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I guess you've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java). Here the answer says that we must be careful when renaming and we must pass a proper path in that method

Comment: This code is weird. You could just create a new file with new content, and delete the old file. Or I am missing something ?

Comment: can you try the below code instead of rename
        Path source = Paths.get("/Users/suman.das/Downloads/data1.csv");
        Files.move(source, source.resolveSibling("data1.csv"), REPLACE_EXISTING);

Comment: Besides your code beeing rather strange (renames file.getOriginalFilename() an existing file and then overwrites it, newFile and "merchant_logo.png" are in different directories which "rename" won't handle) your code is highly insecure!

Never use (insecure) input  directly as filesnames without properly validating them. An external attacker could acces any file that the application is able to acces via your method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am using java 1.8, maybe this will help you out.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, @RequestParam("id") Integer merchantId) throws Exception {
        try {
            File directory = new File(properties.getFileUploadDir(), merchantId.toString());
            directory.mkdirs();
            Path writeTargetPath = Files.write(
                    Paths.get(directory.getAbsolutePath(), file.getOriginalFilename()).toAbsolutePath(),
                    file.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE_NEW);
            Path fileToMovePath = Paths.get(properties.getFileUploadDir(), merchantId.toString(), "merchant_logo.png");
            Path movedPath = Files.move(writeTargetPath, fileToMovePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            log.info("movedPath: {}", movedPath.toAbsolutePath());

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message",
                    "Successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException: {}", e);
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Upload failed'" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Successfully uploaded'" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
    }
```

Comment: I can't resolve `properties`. What I need to import?

Comment: I get error java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /opt/1/download.png How the old file can be overwritten?

Comment: 1. instead of hard coding UPLOADED_FOLDER value, am getting that value from properties file.
2. I have tried with windows, don't have such type of issue, your'e trying with Linux, can you please verify your folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `new File("merchant_logo.png")` as
`new File(directory,"merchant_logo.png")` to write file in right directory.

Also removing the old file before writing new one can help not to have such issues.