# Java Selenium - Rename downloaded files

Tags: java, list, selenium, file, download

I need to know how can I give a specific name to a downloaded file. My program is downloading a lot of files and I need to rename this files with names that exist in a list of strings. Can someone help me?

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on this and please provide an example so that it will be helpful for us to understand the current circumstance :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158777/rename-a-file-using-java

Comment: I have a list of strings (A1, B1,C1...), and for each string my program is searching in a specific page if the string exists. If the string exists the program download the file associated to this string. What I want is to change the name of downloaded file (rename to A1, B1, C1...).