# File.rename() in Java - is it an atomic operation?

Tags: java, linux, unix, file-rename, atomic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to atomically rename a file in Java, even if the dest file already exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595631/how-to-atomically-rename-a-file-in-java-even-if-the-dest-file-already-exists)

I'm working with a process the might be killed in middle of work. I want to rename a file. Is Java's rename operation an atomic operation?

I am interested in the case of Linux, HP-UX, Solaris, and AIX.

Comment: Maybe this question can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595631/how-to-atomically-rename-a-file-in-java-even-if-the-dest-file-already-exists

Comment: But what about process killed scenario?

Comment: @Marcelo: Looks like the other question is about overwrite-by-rename; this one asks about ordinary rename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Rename](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) operation may or may not be atomic and it may or may not succeed
if a file or directory already exists under the target name.On Unix two separate operations
must be performed.  First one must test whether a file exists under the target name.  Then, if no such file exists, one can go ahead and rename the source file to the target name.  Between these two operations a new file might be created under the target name and because the rename() system call is atomic and will destroy the target this new file will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

No.

<strike>At least because VM might be killed exactly after it left your code (after you entered File.rename() ), and before File.rename() code started running.</strike>

Comment: Sorry, I was answering the wrong question. It should be a property of operating system, I believe