# Using Python to Know When a File Has Completely Been Received From an FTP Source

Tags: python, ftp

I am using Python to develop an application that does the following:

- Monitors a particular directory and watches for file to be
  transferred to it. Once the file has finished its transfer, run some
  external program on the file.

The main issue I have developing this application is knowing when the file has finished transferring. From what I know the file will be transferred via SFTP to a particular directory. How will Python know when the file has finished transferring? I know that I can use the `st_size` attribute from the object returned by `os.stat(fileName)` method. Are there more tools that I need to use to accomplish these goals?

Comment: Do you know what the final file size will be? If not `st_size` isn't going to help much, and the only thing you can really do is use `lsof`, a platform-specific library that exposes the functionality `lsof` uses, or a platform-specific filesystem-watcher library.

Comment: Please take a look at the [watchdog](http://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

Comment: Depending on the platform you may also be able to use [pyinotify](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I will not know the size of the file being transferred, and I have just verified that the SFTP server is a Windows machine.

Comment: Because of the fact that I will be using a Windows machine, are there any Windows API calls that I can use with Python for Windows (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) in order determine whether a file has completely transferred. Do files have special EOF markers that show they are complete that Windows can verify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of watchdog and waited until I can open the file for writing

```
 #If there is no error when trying to read the file, then it has completely loaded
    try:
        with io.FileIO(fileName, "r+") as fileObj:

            '''
            Deal with case where FTP client uses extensions such as ".part" and '.filepart" for part of the incomplete downloaded file.
            To do this, make sure file exists before adding it to list of completedFiles.
            '''
            if(os.path.isfile(fileName)):
                completedFiles.append(fileName)
                print "File=" + fileName + " has completely loaded."
    except IOError as ioe:
        print str(ioe)
```

Answer (score 4):

The best way to solve this would be to have the sending process SFTP to a holding area, and then (presumably using SSH) execute a `mv` command to move the file from the holding area to the final destination area. Then, once the file appears in the destination area, your script knows that it is completely transferred.