# Is File.renameTo() atomic in Oracle Java 6 and Windows?

Tags: java, file, file-io

Docs for `File.renameTo()` say: "Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename (...) might not be atomic..."

That is pretty vague and I need disambiguation. Is this method atomic in Oracle Java 6 on WinXP and newer?

Comment: I suspect it depends on whether you are renaming a file in a directory, moving a file around a file system or moving a file between file systems (which is a copy and a delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on this answer[xpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows)

"Win32 does not guarantee atomic file meta data operations. I'd provide a citation, but there is none - that fact that there's no written or documented guarantee means as much"

No.

Answer (score 4):

Since win32 historically didn't provide any support for atomic file moves/renames, that's highly unlikely.

They added functions for this with Vista, so the new file functions in Java7 may actually use those - no idea. But for XP you're out of luck.