# Change target for symbolic link in windows

Tags: windows, filesystems, symlink

How can I change target of already existing symbolic link. Any solution would work: console, powershell,etc.

Important think is to make this change atomically so solution to delete link and then create a new one do not work for me.

Comment: If you wrap the deletion and recreation in a transaction I believe it will be atomic.

Comment: What kind of transaction? File system operation like move file on the same disk I think are atomic. Two file operation are not. Correct me please if I'm wrong.

Comment: See my answer.  Support for transactional NTFS was added in Windows Vista.

Comment: The answer from @Gyan below absolutely works.  I also ran tests and it works for me.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be possible with the [`ZwFsControlFile` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) using the [`FSCTL_SET_REPARSE_POINT` control code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545568%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). At least that's what I gleaned from how Far Manager does it via Process Monitor.

Comment: As of Mar 2017 [Far Manager](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/farmanager/code/trunk/unicode_far/flink.cpp) uses [DeviceIoControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to change/edit either symlink or junction target(s).

Answer (score 2):

You could use transactional NTFS.  See the following functions:

- [CreateTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366011%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [DeleteFileTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363916.aspx)
- [CreateSymbolicLinkTransacted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363867%28v=vs.85%29)
- [CommitTransaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

The downside is that MS are deprecating support for transactions.  In particular transactions are not available in the new file system being introduced in Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Thank you, Harry. Never though that it is possible to have transaction. Unfortunately deprecation is a bad sign so I'm not sure I'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating a new symbolic link, and then renaming the new link to overwrite the old.

There are some possibilities mentioned here:

[Is an atomic file rename (with overwrite) possible on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

A slight modification of LSemi's method works for me in Windows 7 CMD console

```
mklink TempLink NewTarget

copy /l /y TempLink OldLink

del TempLink
```

I've a process that reads OldLink multiple times a second and with this method I'm able to continuously update OldLink to new targets without causing a read error. Strictly speaking, this isn't probably atomic but the time taken to effect the symlink copy must be so small, that it doesn't interfere.

Comment: What does `/l` do?  It's not listed for [Windows Server `copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/copy).

Comment: Windows 7 `copy /?` shows this `/L    If the source is a symbolic link, copy the link to the target instead of the actual file the source link points to.`

Comment: This answer is brilliant.  Why was it downvoted?  If anything, @Gyan, you can add more details, like output of `dir` to show exactly how the file system changes after each step.  I tested your steps: In a separate Cygwin window, I run a simple infinite loop: `while true; do cat symlink.txt; done`.  Then I used your trick to update `symlink.txt` to point to different file.  Never once did my infinite read file loop fail.  Works perfectly.  I wonder how `copy` executes this operation!  It is annoying that `MKLINK` does not have a `/F` (force) option to do the same.  UNIX has it.