# Replace file with another in an atomic operation (Windows)

Tags: c++, windows

I have two files: A and B. I need to replace B with A, while B is opened in another program.

The following approach:

`MoveFile` to rename B to C, then rename A to B, then delete C

works fine. However I need an atomic way to do that, because if one rename fails the data will be left in inconsistent state.

I tried `MoveFileEx` with `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING` flag, but it doesn't work when file B is opened by another program. Same for `ReplaceFile` function. Any other ideas? Thank you

Comment: This isn't an atomic operation, so could you possibly do it in an atomic way? Why can't you just use proper error handling?

Comment: File locks exist for a reason. Try the change, fail if it can't be done.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no way, try reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows) and see if it applies to you.

Comment: Error handling won't work. Let's say the file is on the network. First rename works, second fails, and the third (error handling) will also fail. So I'll leave the files in inconsistent state. Atomic operation is needed

Comment: @Kyle, atomic rename operation exists in Linux (of course, provided that the power supply is not abruptly interrupted, but there is the journal for handling that) and it's a totally legitimate request for any not-a-toy OS.

Comment: @Stefano: the OP is asking for a pair of renames as a single atomic operation.  Does Linux really do that?

Comment: One possible solution is transactions, but that's a deprecated technology; in particular, it won't work on WinFS.  It would probably be better to detect and repair these inconsistencies on the rare occasions when they occur.

Comment: @Harry why a pair? He needs to replace B with A. C is only auxiliary.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo: if he could delete B he wouldn't have a problem, since a move-and-replace is atomic.  Since he can't, he wants to do a pair of renames as an atomic operation.  Windows can actually do that in NTFS but not in WinFS, and the technology is considered deprecated.