# Do we know if Python's open mode 'x' is actually an atomic "create if not exists" under Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, concurrency, atomic

According to the documentation of the [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.open) function in `os`, which I assume is analogous to the high level `open` function in terms of file access modes, the behaviour of the `O_EXCL` flag depends on the underlying operating system, and links to documentation for Linux and Windows. Evidence that 'x' mode is equivalent to `O_EXCL|O_CREAT` can be seen from the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Modules/_io/fileio.c#L285) of Python's C code.

The [Linux page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/manpages-dev/open.2.en.html#O_EXCL) says O_EXCL is atomic, but the [Windows page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/open-wopen?view=msvc-170#remarks) doesn't mention anything about atomicity.

Can any one give evidence that the 'x' mode is indeed atomic under Windows such that there cannot be a race condition where something can happen between checking the file's existence and creating the file?

Comment: last I checked, Windows doesn't even do atomic file renames.  I wouldn't expect anything on Windows to be atomic.

Comment: @Samwise This says that rename under Windows is atomic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/167414/is-an-atomic-file-rename-with-overwrite-possible-on-windows

Comment: ah, last time I had to deal with it was pre-windows 10.  Good for them!  It only took them what, 35 years?  :D